# d3.js transition() not working when browser is minimised

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The ***transition()*** selection which i use to shift the position of *svg* elements when new data  comes in, works perfectly when browser window is open but when I open another tab or minimize  the window, the ***transition()*** function piles the *svg* elements on top of each other. when i open  the window i see piled up *svg* elements on top of each other.

The ***exit()*** selection moves out of screen however.

Comment: Hey I am also facing the same issue with my Scatterplot which takes in dynamic data. As long as the browser is open the plots update but on minimising the browser the page kind of hangs. Is it a memory leak issue???

Answer (score 18, accepted):

D3 [uses requestAnimationFrame](https://twitter.com/mbostock/status/45556964415119361) to enable smooth and efficient drawing. Here is [more info](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) on the topic.

The basic problem many people have is, when a window/tab is in the background, the page rendering "goes to sleep mode" and no "animation frames" are provided, i.e., the browser will stop drawing.

You can work around that "problem" by using the browsers [visibility API](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/PageVisibility/Overview.html) to control your drawing (e.g., do a **complete update** of your charts when the page becomes visible again).
See the [related MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) for examples.

Comment: Nice! I've encountered this issue in the past too, and this workaround sounds promising. I would think that as an alternative to doing a complete update *when the page becomes visible*, one could instead decide whether or not to use `transition()` depending on the visibility state. I.e., say you have a some d3 selection, `mySelection`, which you want to modify its `"x"` attribute; you could call `(document.hidden ? mySelection : mySelection.transition()).attr("x", 12345)`.

Comment: Should this be reported as a feature request? I think the transition() method itself should take care of browser visibility using the page visibility API, and animate accordingly. I dont want to do a complete update of my chart. Instead I would find a way of not animating when not visible as suggested by @meetamit

Comment: Maybe, I did not test it how the `transition` function currently works in BG mode. But if implemented correctly, it should skip the animation and set the DOM to its final state after the `duration`. It must not skip setting the final state completely. I think `requestAnimationFrame` is the correct API for the animation but not for setting the final state.

Comment: For those who use C3 and had painting problems when loading the page on background, the issue has been solved in the [C3 respository](https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/2458)